Users are unable to install or update our app
Our app is built with Flutter.
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

We have received several reports from users who are encountering difficulties when attempting to install or update our app, despite our target SDK version (34) and min SDK version (23) being compatible with their device's Android SDK.
The error messages they are seeing are:
During updates:

This app is no longer compatible with your device. Contact the developers for more info.

During installation:

Your device isn't compatible with this version.

Upon reviewing the Google Play console's device catalogue, the reported device models are listed as supported. Additionally, these devices are not rooted, and the users are able to install other apps without any issues. While most of the affected devices are from the Lava LXX series, there are also reports from users with RealMe/Poco and other similar models.
Previously, we were releasing the app using the "Split per ABI" method. In an effort to resolve the issue, we switched to using the App Bundle format; however, the same problem persists.
What might be causing this compatibility issue?
build.gradle default configs:
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.******"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

We tried sharing direct apk with users and they were able to install and run the app successfully.
Permissions required (as on Google Play console)
android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_AD_ID,
android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_ATTRIBUTION,
android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_TOPICS,
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE,
android.permission.CAMERA,
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
android.permission.INTERNET,
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
android.permission.VIBRATE,
android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE,
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE,
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE,
com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID,
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES,
in.******.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION

Features required (as on Google Play console)
android.hardware.camera,
android.hardware.faketouch,
android.hardware.microphone,
android.hardware.screen.portrait

I tried reverting the manifest file changes, build gradle file changes yet I wasn't able to figure out what could be breaking.
Update:
I reported this issue and had a discussion with the Google Play Developer Support Team. They stated the following:
I’ve looked into your issue and found that your app is not compatible with the device LAVA LXX504, LXX503, LXX501, and POCO X5 PRO due to a conflict in your app’s manifest with the following: 

No supported native platform:x86_64

For more information about implied features, manifest stuff, etc., visit our developer site at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

I am still unsure what am I doing wrong as I have separately mentioned x86_64 ndk support in my gradle default configs

How many users are affected? What have you changed in the current version compared to the last version?

I attempted to revert all changes, but that did not resolve the issue. Consequently, I proceeded to update all Flutter packages to their latest versions. Notably, the issue appears to have started after updating the targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34, which aligns with the timing of the first user report.
To date, over 10 users have reported encountering this issue, and we anticipate further reports as more users experience the problem.
